# ClassCast Exception after applying Proguard

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

I am trying to release an app with proguard enabled. Without proguard, the app works fine. But, with proguard, the app crashes with ClassCastException in the below code.

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(Constant.GET_HOME_BANNER_DATA).buildUpon();

        GsonRequest gsonRequest = new GsonRequest<HomeBannerDataList>(Request.Method.GET, builder.toString(),
                HomeBannerDataList.class, hashHeader, null, new Response.Listener<HomeBannerDataList>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(HomeBannerDataList response) {
                if (response == null || response.size() <= 0) {
                    return;
                }
                if (response.get(0).savingscheme != null) {
                    if (response.get(0).savingscheme.getData() != null && response.get(0).savingscheme.getData().size() > 0) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.get(0).savingscheme.getData().get(0).getDescription())) {
                            Utility.setSavingSchemeText(response.get(0).savingscheme.getData().get(0).getDescription());
                        }
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.get(0).savingscheme.getData().get(0).getMediumimage())) {
                            Utility.setSavingSchemeBanner(Constant.PRODUCT_IMAGE_URL + response.get(0).savingscheme.getData().get(0).getMediumimage());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The exception is as follows.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.g----ls.o----a.beans.HomeBannerData
       at com.grtjewels.oriana.fragment.homefragment.HomeFragmentImpPresenter$1.onResponse(Unknown Source)
       at com.gr----ls.o---na.webservice.GsonRequest.deliverResponse(Unknown Source)
       at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

The proguard rules.pro file is below.

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in D:\AndroidSDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {

#}
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

-dontwarn com.google.**
#-keep class com.google.** { *;}


#-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
#-keepattributes Signature

-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }


#-keep class com.android.volley.** {*;}
#-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.** {*;}
#-keep class com.android.volley.Response$* { *; }
#-keep class com.android.volley.Request$* { *; }
#-keep class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$* { *; }
##-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack$* { *; }
##-keep class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$* { *; }

-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @com.some.package.server.JsonDeserializerWithOptions$FieldRequired public *;
}
#-keep @interface com.some.package.server.JsonDeserializerWithOptions$FieldRequired
#-keep class com.some.package.server.JsonDeserializerWithOptions
#-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher {
#    void processRequest();
#}
#-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation class com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher {
#    void processRequest();
#}
# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}
# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}
# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();

}
-keep class com.g----ls.o----a.beans.** { *; }

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.**
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}
```

I know there is some issue with the proguard file. Can someone please help me solve this??Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you post the ProGuard file

Comment: ok..i will post it.

Answer (score 0):

if im correct, youll have to keep every class that will be de-/serialized by Gson. In this case your *HomeBannerData*.

Have a look in the example rules from the [Gson Sample Project](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg), especially line 14:

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```

Comment: I have kept homeBannerData inside beans folder, which I have included in proguard file,in the below line.  `-keep class com.grtjewels.oriana.beans.** { *; }` but still the problem exists.

Comment: Could you try to add all the other rules from the example? If this does the trick, you could remove them one by one to see what causes the error.

Comment: I also added the other rules, but still the ClasscastException exists.